# Plotting hierarchical clustering dendrograms for large data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a huge data set of time series data. In order to visualise the clustering in python, I want to plot time series graphs along with the dendrogram as shown below. 
[image]

I tried to do it by using subgrid2plot() function in python by creating two subplots side by side. I filled first one with series graphs and second one with dendrograms. But once number of time series increased, it became blur.

Can someone suggest a nice way to plot this type of dendrogram? I have around 50,000 time series to cluster and visualise.

Answer (score 0):

Convert data into JSON with `json` module of python and then use [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) for graph ploting.
[Check the Gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) from here where you can find dendrogram and time series graph